# Method Parameter Completion Shortcut for Intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When calling the method TestMethod, Intellij pops up a helpful message showing what the expected parameter should be (e.g. String test).

Is there a shortcut by which I can get Intellij to pre-fill that with the suggestion, since it already pretty much knows what should be in the method call?

[image: Method]

Comment: What would it fill it with?

Comment: It's only showing you the method signature. It has no way of knowing what you want to actually pass to `TestMethod()`

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Just for reference, Eclipse somewhat stupidly grabs the nearest local variable that extends the type in the method signature.

Comment: Yeah, I'll settle for "stupid"  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, under *certain conditions*:

```
package com.sandbox;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Sandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String s = "";
        passString();
    }

    public static void passString(String foo) {

    }

}
```

See this code?  If you type `passString()` then put your cursor between the parenthesis, you press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>, it will fill that parameter with "s"